# ASP.Net Core 5 Web API scaffolding controller with EF failed. "Rolling back package changes"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, scaffolding

I am trying to scaffold out the 3rd controller in an API I am making. The other 2 worked fine, however now I'm getting the error: "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'myProject'".

This is the model I'm trying to scaffold from:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace CyberpunkAPI.Models
{
    public partial class SpecialAbilities
    {
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public int? Authority { get; set; }
        public int? CharismaticLeadership { get; set; }
        public int? CombatSense { get; set; }
        public int? Credibility { get; set; }
        public int? Family { get; set; }
        public int? Interface { get; set; }
        public int? JuryRig { get; set; }
        public int? MedicalTech { get; set; }
        public int? Resources { get; set; }
        public int? Streedeal { get; set; }

        //public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The process for which I'm trying to do this is:

1. Right click "Controllers"
2. Add > New Scaffold Item
3. API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework

[image: scaffold]

After clicking "Add" I get this error:

[image: error]

What could be causing this and how do I fix it? I don't really have much of an idea where to go from here; the error message is not very helpful.